# Speeding up complex Numpy Matrix multiplications (Point cloud)

Tags: numpy

I have around 200 3D points that I need to multiply into a rather complex 2D projection matrix. I am currently using numpy and a for loop, essentially iterating through 3D point cloud, applying the matrix transformations and getting my data.

This seems rather slow. Is there any way I might be able to vectorize this, or use some kind of speed up techniques (maps, pools etc.)

```
    F = matrix([
        [735.4809,  0.,         388.9476,   0.],
        [0.,        733.6047,   292.0895,   0.],
        [0.,        0.,         1.0000,     0.]
    ])
    VehicleRPY = self.GetRT(Roll=Roll, Pitch=Pitch, Yaw=0., X=IMUX, Y=IMUY, Z=IMUZ);
    SonarToCamera = self.GetRT(Roll=RTRoll, Pitch=RTPitch, Yaw=RTYaw, X=RTX, Y=RTY, Z=RTZ);
    SpaceMatrix = matrix([
        [(sqrt(R**2 - (Y/(cosd(Roll)*cosd(Pitch)))**2)*sind(Theta))],
        [(Y/(cosd(Roll)*cosd(Pitch)))],
        [(sqrt(R**2 - (Y/(cosd(Roll)*cosd(Pitch)))**2)*cosd(Theta))],
        [1]
    ])
    FinalMatrix = F*VehicleRPY*SonarToCamera*SpaceMatrix;
    UVMatrix = matrix([
        [FinalMatrix.item(0)/FinalMatrix.item(2)],
        [FinalMatrix.item(1)/FinalMatrix.item(2)],
    ])
```

Something like the above. I need to repeat this 3*3/4*4 multiplication across 200 points per frame

Comment: Show us what you have so far ...

Comment: added. basically as above. I need to do a multiply of 4x4 matrices where (F*VehicleRPY*SonarToCamera*SpaceMatrix;). I need to do this for each of my 3D points, so I have a big for loop encompassing that function above

Comment: Can you post a working example ? I do not know what size your variables are. E.g by using random variables. Writing the loop explicitly would be good.

Comment: Also profile your code, to see what part takes the most time.

Comment: `np.matrix` is always 2d.  `np.dot` does the same matrix multiplication on `np.arrays`.  It too works with 2d arrays.  But `tensordot` and `einsum` can do this kind of multiplication on higher dimensional arrays.  Extending the `/` to higher dimensions might be trickier.